# When Passing props through 2 components I loose the ability to use .map on the array

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, components, react-props

**The following is the state set:**
[State to be passed](https://i.stack.imgur.com/x7Ufn.png)

**which I pass in the SearchResults Component:**

SearchResults isRemoval='false' onAdd={this.addTrack}
                                       searchResults={this.state.searchResults}/>

*(im aware that the beginning is missing the < symbol I had to leave it out because it was hiding it with the < not omitted)*

**and then in SearchResults I pass the props through to**

```
class SearchResults extends React.Component {

    render() {

        return (
            <div className="SearchResults">
                <h2>Results</h2>

                <TrackList isRemoval={this.props.isRemoval} onAdd={this.props.onAdd}
                           tracks={this.props.searchResults}/>
            </div>
        )
    }

}
```

**And then in Tracklist I try to use map on the array but I get an error saying it cant perform map on  undefined.**

```
class TrackList extends React.Component {


    render() {


        return (<div className="TrackList">

                {

                this.props.tracks.map(track => {
                return <Track  track={track} />
                })
                }
            </div>
        );
    }


}
```

When I call the props in the first component down it is defined and I can use the array as desired but when passed to the second component it shows up undefined in console and I can not use map. Does any one know why this is happening?

Comment: Are you getting this error after taking any actions?

Answer (score 1):

So the problem was I was passing props to the same component from another component that had an error in it. I had forgotten that I was passing props from more than one source thats why I was getting the undefined error. Thanks everyone for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Are you loading that data through something external, and if so does your state have a default value? If you're not setting searchResults as an empty array, initially you won't have a value for `searchResults`.

If that's not the case, there must be some part of the program we're missing here, because the code seems fine.

Try logging each component's entire props every step of the way, you'll get a better idea of when it gets lost.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I have checked the props at every level. and what is frustrating is that the props actually come through in the console but with the array is also an undefinded. I can console.log(this.props.tracks) and it shows up in the console as it should as an array but on the next line there is an undefined.

Comment: On the previous level (in search results there is no undefined) it seems that when I pass the props through more than one component an undefined happens in the console that wont allow me to do operations on the array even though that information is there?

Answer (score 0):

This is an interesting issue you're facing, but I would suggest that you first check if `this.props.tracks` is `null || undefined` before trying to map through it.

If my hypothesis is correct, when the render method for the `TrackList` component initially runs, `this.props.tracks` is undefined, therefore it probably throws an error.

The following code could possibly solve your issue:

```
class TrackList extends React.Component {
    render() {
       return(
          const { tracks } = this.props;
          <div className="TrackList">
            {tracks ? tracks.map(track => {
            return <Track track={track} />;
            }) : null}
          </div>
        );
     }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Child component updates when its state or the parent's state changes but not if parent's props changes.

Create state in SearchResults and pass that state to child component

```
class SearchResults extends React.Component {
    constructor(){
    super();
    this.state = {
     tracks: []
    }
  }

componentWillReceiveProps(newProps){
  if(newProps.searchResults){
   this.setState({
     tracks: newProps.searchResults
    });
   }
 }

render() {

    return (
        <div className="SearchResults">
            <h2>Results</h2>

            <TrackList isRemoval={this.props.isRemoval} onAdd={this.props.onAdd}
                       tracks={this.state.tracks}/>
        </div>
    )
 }

}
```

Same Applies to other props too..

Hope this helps